# Customize output style of views filter fields

Tags: views, 8, theming

I have a view associated with many filter fields:

- Checkboxes
- Listboxes
- **Three date fields of textbox type.**

In admin theme(seven), the date filter fields aligned improperly and I would like to show the three date range filters aligned horizontally next to each other.

I couldn't add any class for filter fields from the admin UI.

Any help/ideas please?

Answer (score 1):

The CSS classes given by Views should normally be good enough, if you don't know how to find them you may using a chrome or firefox browser: **right click** on the filter field and then **inspect element**

Or if you want you may install the [Better exposed filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) module and follow the intructions given in [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/100255/how-to-add-custom-css-classes-to-views-exposed-filters/100256)

**UPDATE:**

As per your comment below, **how to group filter fields under one div ?**, it is out of the scope of the original question and for that you will have to ask another question.

However, I believe that what you are asking for is not doable using the views UI and you will have to write your own custom codes, for that you may find the below links somehow useful even if they are referencing the D7 version:

- [Wrapping fields together in a views exposed filter](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/179217/wrapping-fields-together-in-a-views-exposed-filter)
- [Place exposed filters in a fieldset](https://www.zyxware.com/articles/3058/solved-drupal-views-drupal-7-how-to-place-exposed-filters-in-a-fieldset)
- [Views Grouping field to use a shared wrapper div](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/theme-development/2012-03-05/views-grouping-fields-to-use-a-shared-wrapper-div)
- [Views exposed groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_exposed_groups) Module for D7

Comment: Thanks for the edit and answer. It is really give me an option to style the element. But is it possible to group elements inside a div, like `<div id="startdate-group"> < here come the first date range field </div>' and `<div id="enddate-group"> < here come the second date range field </div>'`. I think i should update or ask a different question for this.